Colorama messing up ascii
I have recently started work on a chess program. I coded the program to take a 2d array that I made and decode it to form a chess board using ascii characters and colorama. I coded it up so that R=Rook, B=Bishop, P=Pawn, N=Knight, K=King, Q=Queen. There are some extra characters but they are only necessary for parsing and other stuff. Here is my code:
from colorama import Fore, Back

pos=[
    ["u3wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "uwK", "wB", "wN", "u2wR"],
    ["uwP", "uwP", "uwP", "uwP", "uwP", "uwP", "uwP", "uwP"],
    ["E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"],
    ["E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"],
    ["E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"],
    ["E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E"],
    ["ubP", "ubP", "ubP", "ubP", "ubP", "ubP", "ubP", "ubP"],
    ["u3bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "ubK", "bB", "bN", "u2bR"]
]

def print_board(pside):
    if pside=="white":
        for i in range(7, -1, -1):
            print("", end="\n")
            for j in range(0, 7):
                if "K" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♚", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♚", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♔", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♔", end="")
                if "Q" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♛", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♛", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♕", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♕", end="")
                if "R" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♜", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♜", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♖", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♖", end="")
                if "B" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♝", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♝", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♗", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♗", end="")
                if "N" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♞", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♞", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♘", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♘", end="")
                if "P" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♟", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♟", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♙", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♙", end="")
                if "E" in pos[i][j]:
                    if (j + i)%2==0:
                        print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "  ", end="")
                    else:
                        print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "  ", end="")
    else:
        for i in range(0, 8):
            print("", end="\n")
            for j in range(7, -1, -1):
                if "K" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♚", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♚", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♔", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♔", end="")
                if "Q" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♛", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♛", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♕", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♕", end="")
                if "R" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♜", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♜", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♖", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♖", end="")
                if "B" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♝", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♝", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♗", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♗", end="")
                if "N" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♞", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♞", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♘", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♘", end="")
                if "P" in pos[i][j]:
                    if "b" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "♟", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "♟", end="")
                    else:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.WHITE + "♙", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.WHITE + Back.BLACK + "♙", end="") 
                    if "E" in pos[i][j]:
                        if (j + i)%2==0:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + "  ", end="")
                        else:
                            print(Fore.BLACK + Back.BLACK + "  ", end="") 
print_board("white")

When I run the code, I do get the appropriate output, but the ascii chars kind of get merged together and form 2 characters of space from 2 ascii chars, where 1 ascii char itself takes up 2 characters of space. I think StackOverflow will format it automatically, but here is the output in text:
♜♞♝♛♚♝♞
♟♟♟♟♟♟♟
              
              
              
              
♙♙♙♙♙♙♙
♖♘♗♕♔♗♘

This is an image:

How do I fix this? Can anyone help?

How do I fix this? Most probably your terminal that you are uisng is not able to render the unicode characters correctly. Try with a different terminal. Also you are priting two whitespaces "  " for a blank space instead of one, which makes the middle rows run to the right.

@KamilCuk I am using VS Code Insiders as my terminal. I do not have any extensions enabled on VS Code Insiders that would mess up with the terminal. I also tried it out on the original VS Code and got the same result. When I wrote two spaces and one emoji under and below each other in the code, I saw that it was the same size, that's why I used two spaces. If I notice that two spaces are too much for one emoji, I will reduce it appropriately. I am also on windows.
